# Is webdrivermanager supporting RemoteWebDriver (Selenium Grid)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

I've updated the dependency for the WebDrivermanager in my pom.xml file. 
while running the code in my local like below it seems working fine.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(capability);
```

but when I tried to run the code Remotely with RemoteWebDriver, it failed and keep asking to add binaries for browsers

```
URL remote_grid = new URL("http://" + seleniumHub + ":" + seleniumHubPort + "/wd/hub");
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(remote_grid, capability);
```

It throws below exception.

```
[Invoker 1386767190] Keeping method SeleniumInit.setUp(java.lang.reflect.Method, org.testng.ITestContext)[pri:0, instance:com.wo2.commonfucntion.index.LoginIndex@598067a5] for class [TestClass name=class com.wo2.commonfucntion.index.LoginIndex]
[Invoker 1386767190] Keeping method SeleniumInit.tearDown(org.testng.ITestResult)[pri:0, instance:com.wo2.commonfucntion.index.LoginIndex@598067a5] for class [TestClass name=class com.wo2.commonfucntion.index.LoginIndex]
[Invoker 1386767190] Keeping method SeleniumInit.setUp(java.lang.reflect.Method, org.testng.ITestContext)[pri:0, instance:com.wo2.commonfucntion.index.LoginIndex@598067a5] for class [TestClass name=class com.wo2.commonfucntion.index.LoginIndex]
[Invoker 1386767190] Invoking @BeforeMethod SeleniumInit.setUp(java.lang.reflect.Method, org.testng.ITestContext)[pri:0, instance:com.wo2.commonfucntion.index.LoginIndex@598067a5]
13:27:40.503 [main] INFO  i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.BrowserManager - Reading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/ to seek [chromedriver]
13:27:41.358 [main] INFO  i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.BrowserManager - Latest version of [chromedriver] is 2.30
13:27:41.368 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Downloader - Using binary driver previously downloaded C:\Users\zara\.m2\repository\webdriver\chromedriver\win32\2.30\chromedriver.exe
13:27:41.368 [main] INFO  i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.BrowserManager - Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as C:\Users\zara\.m2\repository\webdriver\chromedriver\win32\2.30\chromedriver.exe
========= Google Chrome Browser ==========
Failed to invoke configuration method com.wo2.init.SeleniumInit.setUp:The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
Command duration or timeout: 120 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ICWS-1162', ip: '192.168.0.42', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
[Invoker 1386767190] Keeping method SeleniumInit.tearDown(org.testng.ITestResult)[pri:0, instance:com.wo2.commonfucntion.index.LoginIndex@598067a5] for class [TestClass name=class com.wo2.commonfucntion.index.LoginIndex]
[Invoker 1386767190] Invoking @AfterMethod SeleniumInit.tearDown(org.testng.ITestResult)[pri:0, instance:com.wo2.commonfucntion.index.LoginIndex@598067a5]

TEST FAILED - validLogin

ERROR MESSAGE: null


message from tear downjava.lang.NullPointerException
===== Invoked methods
  SeleniumInit.fetchSuiteConfiguration(org.testng.ITestContext)[pri:0, instance:com.wo2.commonfucntion.index.LoginIndex@598067a5]org.testng.TestRunner@485e36bc  1501587365
    LoginIndex.validLogin()[pri:0, instance:com.wo2.commonfucntion.index.LoginIndex@598067a5] 1501587365
=====
Creating D:\Rahul_P-QA\Intech_Workspace\WO2_QA\WO2_QA\test-output\Work Order - 2\WO2_SC_001 _ To verify user can login successfully..html
Creating D:\Rahul_P-QA\Intech_Workspace\WO2_QA\WO2_QA\test-output\Work Order - 2\WO2_SC_001 _ To verify user can login successfully..xml
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp(public void com.wo2.commonfucntion.index.LoginIndex.validLogin(), org.testng.TestRunner@485e36bc)
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
Command duration or timeout: 120 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ICWS-1162', ip: '192.168.0.42', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact WebDriverManager can help with the setup of Selenium Grid. The process would be as follows:

1. Start hub and nodes. You can do it using the command line (`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<version>.jar standalone`), or use a Java class with the help of WebDriverManager to download the proper drivers. Here you can find an [example](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/StartHub.java) using Chrome and Firefox as browsers.
2. Run your test, connecting to the URL's hub. Here another [example](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/remote/RemoteTest.java).

Comment: The answer is very sound, but the second link is broken.  Would you mind researching when you get the chance?

Comment: @user662913 Fixed